# Do relational restrictions keep me from deleting parent records?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

Let's say I have a table with a uniquely indexed column called `user_name` that's keyed to a comment table with a column name `user_name` as a foreign key. I have some options about actions to take, specifically 1) `on update` and 2) `on delete`.

I understand that some of these options are to `Cascade` the effects of these relations, such as if I remove a parent node from a parent table, child records with foreign keys will be removed, i.e. if I remove a user, all their comments should disappear if their keyed to a user. I believe this would be an `on delete` => `cascade` option which would be a similar thing for `on update`, like changing a user name which changes the comment owners names.

My question is, if I were to `update` a parent record and the action was to `restrict`, would this mean that a parent record's foreign key could not change because it had set child records? Are these actions only talking about what to do with child records if parent records are changed? Also, if I were to set `delete` to `restrict`, would this mean that I would not be able to delete a parent record if it already had a child record in place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. if I were to update a parent record and the action was to restrict, would this mean that a parent record's foreign key could not change because it had set child records?

   *Yes, you would get an error and parent record won't be updated*
2. Are these actions only talking about what to do with child records if parent records are changed?

   *Yes*
3. if I were to set delete to restrict, would this mean that I would not be able to delete a parent record if it already had a child record in place?

   *Yes, you would get an error*

There's another options [available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

- **SET NULL** - when parent row needs to be deleted/updated, all child rows will
  be set to NULL
- **NO ACTION** - equivalent to RESTRICT

If you need to disable foreign key checks for current session/query you could do:

```
mysql> SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
mysql> SOURCE dump_file_name;
mysql> another query;
mysql> SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```